# Changing navigationBar.title according to mode/case?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, switch-statement, navigationbar

I have viewController, which has three cases/three modes.

It has a 'Create New Person' mode, a 'Show Person' mode and finally a 'Edit Person' mode. This all works fine - but I can't seem to set the navigationBar.title according to mode/case.

Here's the relevant code:

```
private func modeUpdate() {
   let createNewPerson:[NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor.rawValue):UIColor.blue, NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.font.rawValue):UIFont(name:"Create New Person", size: 17)!]
   let showPerson:[NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor.rawValue):UIColor.blue, NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.font.rawValue):UIFont(name:"", size: 17)!]
   let editPerson:[NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor.rawValue):UIColor.blue, NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.font.rawValue):UIFont(name:"Edit Person", size: 17)!]


    switch mode {
    case .create:
        actionButton.title = "Save"
        personName.isEditable = true
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = createNewPerson
        question.isEditable = false
        personAnswer.isEditable = true
        extraIdentifier.isEditable = false
        extraIdentifierAnswer.isEditable = true

    case .show:
        actionButton.title = "Edit"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = showPerson
        personName.isEditable = false
        question.isEditable = false
        personAnswer.isEditable = false
        extraIdentifier.isEditable = false
        extraIdentifierAnswer.isEditable = false

    case .edit:
        actionButton.title = "Save"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = editPerson
        personName.isEditable = true
        question.isEditable = false
        personAnswer.isEditable = true
        extraIdentifier.isEditable = false
        extraIdentifierAnswer.isEditable = true
    }
}
```

It all compiles, but when I enter either one of the three cases on my device, I get: 'Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' on the line 'let createNewPerson:[NSAttributed....'

Does anyone know why this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: we are missing a lot of the picture, so can only guess that something that's optional, you're force-unwrapping? ie: `!`

Comment: Well, I'm force-unwrapping all the three 'let lines', in which I declare the different titles. But when I try to unwrap it into Any, as xCode suggest, when I remove the !-marks, the navigationBar.title remains empty - and the app crashes, when trying to use navigationController to get back from one of the cases...

Comment: You need to learn about the syntax :) UIFont and NavigationBarTitle is different thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `self.navigationItem.title = "text"`